# How to Implement Hierarchical Query in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have some table "tab1", which contains the sample data as like follws

[image: Existed data in the database]

I am expecting the output like as follows

[image: Expected output]

How to implement in "BIGQUERY", Please help me to achieve this.

Thanks
Kalyan

Comment: could you please describe your logic of this output

Comment: If you see the existed data table, term1 has definition 'xyz' and it was given on 01-jan-2018, but for the same term a new definition has given on 01-apr-2018. so the term1 first definition was valid from 01-jan-2018 to 01-apr-2018. this will continued as long as new definitions were added. its kind of slowly changing dimension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need `lead()`:

```
select t.*,
       lead(effective_from, 1, date('9999-12-31')) over
           (partition by sno
            order by effective_from
           ) as effective_to
from t
```